# Meaning of **kwargs attribute put in classes of Machine Learning Models

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am wondering about the meaning of the attribute `**kwargs` that I've found typically added in the constructor of some machine learning models classes. For example considering a neural network in PyTorch:

```
class Model(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, **kwargs)
```

is `**kwargs` associated with extra parameters that are defined later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to machine learning models classes, it is rather a Python feature.

You are indeed right, it corresponds to additional keyword arguments. It will essentially collect the remaining passed named argument, that are not defined in the function header, and add them to the *dictionary* variable `kwargs`. This variable can actually be renamed to any name, it is customary to keep `'args'` for iterable unnamed arguments (`*args`) and `'kwargs'` for keyword arguments (`**kwargs`).

This adds the flexibility to allow for additional arguments to be defined and passed to the function without having to specifically state their names in the header. One common use case is when extending a class. Here we are implementing a dummy 3x3 2D convolution layer named `Conv3x3`, which will extends the base [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) module:

```
class Conv3x3(nn.Conv2d):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(kernel_size=3, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, we didn't need to name all arguments and we still keep the same interface as `nn.Conv2d` in our `Conv3x3` class initializer:

```
>>> Conv3x3(in_channels=3, out_channels=16)
Conv3x3(3, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
```

---

There are a lot of nice things you can do with these two constructs. Much of which you can find on [here](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/).

Comment: many thanks Ivan. So in the Conv3x3 class that you create you just specify **kwargs BOTH on class constructor and on super class constructors... specifying kernel_size=3 in super you will extend your Conv2D class with stuff by maintaining a fixed kernel size specified on the super constructor right?

Comment: That's exactly right James. You can actually check the value of `kwargs` in the initializer, it's nothing more than a *dict* containing the user-provided arguments, here: `{'in_channels': 3, 'out_channels': 16}`. This is just a specific use case for packing/unpacking *dict*s. You can play around with it, for example (just for demonstration purposes): use `super().__init__(**{'kernel_size':3, **kwargs})`. Here the side effect is that you can overwrite `kernel_size':3` by providing it in the `kwargs`: *i.e.* `Conv3x3(in_channels=3, out_channels=16, kernel_size=4)` will have a kernel size of `4`.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `**kwargs` refers to keyword arguments; so yes, they can be used for later additions.
See e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_arbitrary_keyword_arguments.asp